# How to execute the main file while being in sub-file in TexMaker?

Tags: texmaker, shortcut

I am using TexMaker on Linux. I have a `main.tex` file which contains a sub-file `subfile.tex` by the command

```
\input{subfile}
```

Now, I am being in the `subfile.tex`, how can I execute (''quick build'') the `main.tex` file without moving to `main.tex`.

In Overleaf, we can do that by simply press `Ctrl + Enter`. Is there a similar shortcut for Texmaker?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254749/texmaker-compiling-a-parent-file

Comment: @JérômeLAURENS Yes, it works! thank you so much!